# what is the actual parameter for the locale=I18nData.country_code(request.location.country)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, locale

First, install gem geocoder and gem i18n_data to make this work.

I ran a test on this `locale=I18nData.country_code(request.location.country)` with a slight tweak (for testing purposes). This is what i actually did

```
@country=I18nData.country_code("Spain")
```

this returns

```
@country="ES"
```

however when i just did

```
@country=I18nData.country_code("spain")
```

it did not display the output. it is clear that the letter of **spain** needs to be capital **S** but when the web application goes live would `@country=I18nData.country_code(request.location.country)` actually give the true parameter which is "Spain"?

Any help towards it would really help me to clarify this confusion! 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking question here and there and with testing, the answer is, the above method extracts **"Spain"** and explicitly set locale as "ES"

Comment: Interesting, for me `request.location` in a controller method throws `undefined method 'location' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x2230050>`. Where are you putting this code?

Comment: First, install gem geocoder and gem i18n_data. Place them in your application controller

Comment: Ahh, ok. I think you should've included that in your question.